# Android Bluetooth headset only works once

Tags: java, android, mobile, bluetooth, headset

Good afternoon Stack Overflow. A friend of mine asked me for help with his Android application. He is trying to make a Bluetooth headset  pick up his voice when a button on the headset is pressed.

The app runs fine, and when the button is pressed it properly picks up the voice. However, after one initial success when he presses the button nothing happens. His code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mHeadsetProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

    Intent reconocimientovoz=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        reconocimientovoz.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        reconocimientovoz.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,1);

        reconocimientovoz.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Escuchando");
        startActivityForResult(reconocimientovoz, REQUEST_CODE);


}
```

He says that if he removes the following line:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mHeadsetProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
```

The app works fine, however it obviously uses the phone mic instead of the headset mic.

I've never worked with Bluetooth before, so honestly I don't have the slightest clue of what's wrong. Would anyone mind nudging us in the right direction?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.